# df.plot adding to itself instead of in separate figure

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe

The following code should give me separate charts each with one line of data, but for some reason the first figure shows the 'GrowthVsValue' line, then the second figure shows me the 'GrowthVsValue' line again and adds the 'LargeVsSmall' line.  But I want them to be on there own in separate figures.  What do I need to add/do to make this work??

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
pp = PdfPages('Relative Strength.pdf')

Output = pd.DataFrame({

'GrowthVsValueDIFF': 1 + (df_ch['IVV'] - df_ch['IVE']),
'LargeVsSmallDIFF':  1 + (df_ch['IVV'] - df_ch['IJR']),

}, index = df_ch.index)


Output['GrowthVsValue'] = 100
Output.loc[1:, 'GrowthVsValue'] = Output.GrowthVsValueDIFF[1:].cumprod() * 100
Output.GrowthVsValue.plot.line(legend=None)
Output.GrowthVsValue_L = plt.title('Growth v. Value RS')
plt.savefig(pp, format='pdf')

Output['LargeVsSmall'] = 100
Output.loc[1:, 'LargeVsSmall'] = Output.LargeVsSmallDIFF[1:].cumprod() * 100
Output.LargeVsSmall.plot.line(legend=None)
Output.LargeVsSmall_L = plt.title('Large v. Small RS')
plt.savefig(pp, format='pdf')

pp.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `plt.close()` after the first `plt.savefig()`

Comment: Its always something simple ha!  Thank you!